# SQLite: Generate rows for missing years within range (system year + 9)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite 3.38.2 table that has rows for certain years:

```
with data (year_, amount) as (
values 
(2024, 100),
(2025, 200),
(2025, 300),
(2026, 400),
(2027, 500),
(2028, 600),
(2028, 700),
(2028, 800),
(2029, 900),
(2031, 100)
)
select * from data
```

| YEAR_ | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2024 | 100 |
| 2025 | 200 |
| 2025 | 300 |
| 2026 | 400 |
| 2027 | 500 |
| 2028 | 600 |
| 2028 | 700 |
| 2028 | 800 |
| 2029 | 900 |
| 2031 | 100 |

Here's the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5qRAnlum).

I want at least one row for each year within this range: `system year + 9`. In other words, I want rows for 10 years, starting with the current year (currently 2023).

However, I'm missing rows for certain years: 2023, 2030, and 2032. So I want to generate filler  rows for those missing years. The `amount` for the filler rows would be `null`.

It would look like this:

| YEAR_ | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2023 | --filler |
| 2024 | 100 |
| 2025 | 200 |
| 2025 | 300 |
| 2026 | 400 |
| 2027 | 500 |
| 2028 | 600 |
| 2028 | 700 |
| 2028 | 800 |
| 2029 | 900 |
| 2030 | --filler |
| 2031 | 100 |
| 2032 | --filler |

In an SQLite query, how can I select the rows and generate filler rows within the 10 year range?

**Edit:** I would prefer not to manually create a list of years in the query or in a table. I would rather create a dynamic range within the query.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a calendar table approach, which will require keeping a table containing all years which you want to appear in your report.  Left join this calendar table to your current table to get the result you want.

```sql
WITH years AS (
    SELECT 2023 AS YEAR_ UNION ALL
    SELECT 2024 UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 2040
)

SELECT y.YEAR_, d.AMOUNT
FROM years y
LEFT JOIN data d
    ON d.YEAR_ = y.YEAR_
WHERE d.YEAR_ BETWEEN SYSYEAR AND SYSYEAR + 9
ORDER BY d.YEAR_;
```

Note that in practice, rather than using the above CTE `years`, you may create a bona fide table containing the next hundred years in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is using a recursive approach to generate your N dates:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
     SELECT 2023 AS year_
  
     UNION ALL
   
     SELECT year_ + 1
     FROM cte
     WHERE year_ < 2023 + (10) -1
)
SELECT cte.year_, data.amount
FROM      cte
LEFT JOIN data
       ON cte.year_ = data.year_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eop6EYpXK5AYQpecbos6K5/0).

Comment: Thanks! For my notes, I can add a unique ID to the query using row_number: `row_number() over (ORDER BY cte.year_, amount) as rownum`.